# wp-types plugin : Cretae Custom Fields Groups is not working in genesis

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields, genesis

I am using genesis 2.1.2 and I installed Types. But the Custom Fields Groups is not working. When I click on create new group it's showing me blank page. If I change the theme to default or to any other then it works but not on GENESIS. is there any reason for this? What should I do?

[image: Here is that blank page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Did you checked PHP error log?**

May be this is happening because of MEMORY LIMITS

Change WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT to 300M in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '300M' );
```